# Setting a local rep as a git and merging with an existing remote

Tags: linux, github, merge, repository

I created a Git repository and worked on it for a while (kept both local and remote synchronized), then I had some issues with my disk quota and had to delete the .git of the local repository (so basically now it's not a git rep, just a normal folder).

I kept working on this version for a while without syncing with the remote. Now I'd like to set the local folder as a git and linked it with existing remote repository (as a new branch, perhaps). I was wondering which commands I should use?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following but I **strongly** encourage you to make a backup of your local repository first.

Once you've done it, try to:

1. Enter your local repository, placing you at top of it, that is: where your former `.git` repository used to be;
2. Reinit your repository running `git init`. This will recreate a new `.git` subfolder, without overwriting the files already in it. You won't have any local and **initial** commit neither;
3. Re-add the initial upstream remote source using `git remote add origin <url to former remote repository>`
4. Update remote states with `git remote update`. This will fetch back all previous objects as well as remote branch names;
5. Force creation of a local "master" branch pointing at where the remote branch is: `git branch -f master origin/master`. You need to force it because you have no existing branch nor initial commit;
6. This should have automatically set upstream branch, but if not, do it with `git branch master -u origin/master`
7. You now should be set on the branch, but since your index is empty too, it will show up as "deleted files" in git's status. You need to bring back the index to branch's state without touching working directory, which is exactly the default mode (aka "--mixed") of the reset command: `git reset origin/master`
8. Just run `git status` and `git diff` to compare the state of your work to last known state of your repository.